# How should I handle two asynchronous calls in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

I have a controller which loads different attributes of my data via two separate http calls.  An overly simplified example would be something like:

- A Country class which has attributes name, official language, and population
- one service (A) which returns countries and their languages
- another service (B) which returns countries and their populations
- let's assume that the set of countries returned in B is a subset of the countries returned in A, and I don't know either set ahead of time
- I want to end up with an array of Country objects - all countries returned by A, with their populations set (based on the data returned by B)

If the calls were synchronous, I would simply do something like:

```
- call service A and store Objects in a map keyed by Country name
- call service B, iterate over results:  if a result in is the previous map, then update its population field
```

But of course I can't do that because the call to service B might return first, so the map is empty.

I have tried using promises via the "$broadcast"/"$on" functionality, but this doesn't work consistently because both calls are asynchronous (I broadcast when B is done, and try to apply the results to A, but sometimes A has not finished yet).

What should I do here?

Comment: Just execute the second function in the callback of the first?

Answer (score 1):

Just look at the [Chained Promises](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-chained-promises)

Comment: Just a thought, you should consider editing this to show an example. The video was useful, and it would suck to see this flagged as not an answer and deleted. If that link were to break, an example would ensure it's still useful to future visitors who have the same problem. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

**Promises** allow developers to easily attach 1x-only notifications of response to any asynchronous request/action. Promises also enable two (2) other very important things. We can:

Transform the responses before subsequent handlers (in the chain) are notified of the response.
Use the response to invoke more async requests (which could generate more promises).
But even more important than the features above, Promises support easy chaining of custom activity or computations. Managing sequences or chains of asynchronous activity can be a very difficult and complex effort. Promise chains are amazing and provide means to easily build sequences of asynchronous requests or asynchronous activity.

Refer - [Flattening Promise Chains](http://solutionoptimist.com/2013/12/27/javascript-promise-chains-2/)

Comment: You referred nice article.

Answer (score 1):

```
    var app = angular.module("app",[]);


    app.factory('myService', function($http,$q) {
        return {
            getPerson: function(){

            return $q.all([
                $http.jsonp('http://filltext.com/?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&rows=10&delay=2&fname={firstName}&lname={lastName}'),
                $http.jsonp('http://filltext.com/?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&rows=10&delay=2&fname={firstName}&city={city}')
                ]).then(
                function(result) { return result },  /* SUCCESS */
                function() { return "NaN" } /* FAILURE */
                );
            }
        };
    });
```